# React useEffect weird behavior

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a form component that gets its state from its parent. The form component just renders a few input fields and others.

The parent component uses useReducer and passes the values down to the form component.

There are two parent components one that lets the user create with the form and one that lets them edit.

In the edit parent component i use useEffect to fetch data from an api and set the initial state from the server.

In development build it sometimes breaks when the component is rendered with the following error:

Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

and in production build it breaks every time when the component is rendered.

```
const Form = ({ state, dispatch }) => {
    return ...form elements;
}

const ParentComponent = ({ match }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await apiCall(match.params.id);
            dispatch({ type: 'overwrite', value: data });
        }

        fetchData();
    }, [match.params.id]);

    return <Form state={state} dispatch={dispatch} />
}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. I also tried to put fetchData on root level and wrap it with useCallback but it has no impact.

Comment: can you show your form component

Comment: The `ParentComponent` seems to be ok as you use `[match.params.id]` when calling useState. This error often occurs when using `useState` without specifying it. Are you the the problem comes from the `ParentComponent` ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me, here is a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/6jj92nm0k.
I suggest stripping down your code to something similar to this exemple and work your way back to your original code step by step.